# How to assign values to local variables using let in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define (range rlist)
(let (
([start (car rlist)])
([step (cdr rlist)])
([end (cddr rlist)]))
end
))
```

Tried doing something like this but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: A: try erasing  the brackets. Q: what is your test call? in what Scheme and how do you run it? what is the error message? do provide verbatim copies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some parentheses in your code are misplaced, here's the correct syntax for `let` using the recommended indentation:

```
(define (range rlist)
  (let ([start (car  rlist)]
        [step  (cdr  rlist)]
        [end   (cddr rlist)])
    end))
```

Notice that you're not using `start` and `step`, and it's possible that `cdr` and `cddr` are being misused (perhaps you meant to use `cadr` and `caddr`), but I can't tell for sure without a sample of the expected input.